# Array Printing Java

Tags: java, arrays, printing

Basically I want my code to enable the user to enter x amount of integers (they chose x), then they will then store each of their inputted integer values in my array.

For some reason when I print my array out after all values have been entered:

I get this:

Code:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many integers will you enter:");
    int amount = input.nextInt();

    int myArray[] = new int[amount];

    for (int counter = 0; counter < amount; counter ++){
        myArray[counter] = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(myArray);
```

Console:

```
        How many integers will you enter:2
        4
        2
       [I@55f96302
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you can take away the for loop and do it this way

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

I would strongly recommend to do it with the for loop. 
It prints one element at the time every time the loop runs, and with your for loop it runs through every element. You need to change the println to this (inside you for loop)

```
System.out.println(myArray[counter]);
```

or if you want to have the array on the same line

```
System.out.print(myArray[counter]+ " ");
```

Later on when programming you are going to see how useful this is compared to Arrays.toString() method.

Answer (score 1):

The string you get is the object notation of array which is expected `[I@55f96302` where

- `[I` is the class name

  - `[` one dimentional array
  - `I` integer array
- `@` joins the string
- `55f96302` some hash code

To print array do

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

or you can simply loop through each element of array

Answer (score 0):

You can also use java.util.ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>(amount);

for (int counter = 0; counter < amount; counter ++){
 myArray.add(counter,input.nextInt());
}
System.out.println(myArray);
```

prints array like this -> [1, 2, 3, 4]